# Slug problems show with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have model:

```
class Header extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
    
}
```

my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $headers = DB::table('headers')->find($id);
    $blocks = DB::table('blocks')->where('header_id', $id)->get();
    return view('test', compact('headers', 'blocks'));
}
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/{id}', [MainController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

but I can't show slug, I see localhost:8000/id
error: Attempt to read property "id" on null

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getRouteKeyName` which is useful for Route-Key binding. But your route is not set up that way.

It also does not help you with the `find()` method in the Model.

Also, you are not using your model in your DB call. Any methods or properties defined in your model will therefore not be used.

And you should set up relationships to get related data.

Respecting your current route, you should do something like this:

```
class Header extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'slug'; 
    // ^-- this is what you use to tell Model what column to use for find()

    // only use this if you do route-model binding
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    // relationship to find all blocks that belong to this header_id
    public function blocks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Model\Blocks::class);
    }
    
}
```

Then for the DB Call:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $header = Headers::find($id);
    $blocks = $header->blocks ?? [];
    return view('test', compact('header', 'blocks'));
}
```